# Adding distances covered by ID's and adding that value to a column on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

The `grouped` dataframe have the following description:

1. USER: represent a user;
2. PRESUMED_RESIDENCE: the antenna closest to the user's place of residence;
3. CALL_LOC: the antenna closest to the place where the user made a call.

the `grouped` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

df = pd.DataFrame({'USER':[1,2,3,1,1,2],
                   'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD1', 'LD', 'TR', 'SVM']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'USER': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD1', 'TR', 'SVM']})

merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='USER', right_on='USER')

grouped = merged.groupby('USER').agg({'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE': min, 'ANTENNA_ID':list}).reset_index()

grouped['ANTENNA_ID'] = [[z for z in x if z!=y]
                         for x,y in zip(grouped['ANTENNA_ID'],
                                       grouped['PRESUMED_RESIDENCE'])]

grouped = grouped.rename(columns={'ANTENNA_ID': 'CALL_LOC'})
```

The dataframe `antennas_loc` contains a pair of cordinates for each antenna:

```
antennas_loc = pd.DataFrame({'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD2', 'TR', 'SVM'],'LAT': [-22.98, -22.97, -22.92, -22.87, -22.89], 'LONG': [-43.19, -43.39, -43.24, -43.28, -43.67]})
antennas_loc
```

Below, I used the `dist` function for calculate the distance of between the antennas:

```
def dist(x, y):
    
    lat1 = radians(x[0])
    lon1 = radians(x[1])
    lat2 = radians(y[0])
    lon2 = radians(y[1])
    
    R = 6373.0
    
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    
    a = sin(dlat/2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    
    distance = R * c
    
    return round(distance, 4)

distances = pdist(antennas_loc[['LAT', 'LONG']].values, metric=dist)

points = antennas_loc['ANTENNA_ID'].values

result = pd.DataFrame(squareform(distances), columns=points, index=points)

result
```

What I need to do now is to create a column on the grouped dataframe that represents the distance traveled by the user, based on his `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE`. Taking user 1 as an example, the calculation would be as follows:

1. `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE`: SJDR1
2. `CALL_LOC`: [LD2, TR]
3. Distance traveled:
   (distance between SJDR1 and LD2) + (distance between SJDR1 and TR).

The line for user 1 would look like this:

```
USER | PRESUMED_RESIDENCE | CALL_LOC | TRAVELLED_DISTANCE
 1   |       SJDR1        | [LD2, TR]|      23,7326
```

However, I have no idea how I can consult the dataframe result, search for the coordinates of residence and calculate the distance from that point to the places of connection. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your first dataframe is actually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'USER':[1,2,3,1,1,2],
                   'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD1', 'LD2', 'TR', 'SVM']})
```

Then this should do it:

```
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

df = pd.DataFrame({'USER': [1,2,3,1,1,2],
                   'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD1', 'LD2', 'TR', 'SVM']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'USER': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD1', 'TR', 'SVM']})

merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on='USER', right_on='USER')
merged = merged[merged['ANTENNA_ID'] != merged['PRESUMED_RESIDENCE']]

antennas_loc = pd.DataFrame({'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD1', 'LD2', 'TR', 'SVM'],
                             'LAT': [-22.98, -22.97, -22.92, -22.87, -22.89],
                             'LONG': [-43.19, -43.39, -43.24, -43.28, -43.67]})

def dist(x, y):
    lat1 = radians(x[0])
    lon1 = radians(x[1])
    lat2 = radians(y[0])
    lon2 = radians(y[1])

    R = 6373.0

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    distance = R * c

    return round(distance, 4)

distances = pdist(antennas_loc[['LAT', 'LONG']].values, metric=dist)

points = antennas_loc['ANTENNA_ID'].values

result = pd.DataFrame(squareform(distances), columns=points, index=points)
melt_df = pd.melt(result.reset_index(), id_vars='index')
melt_df.rename(columns={'index': 'ANTENNA_ID', 'variable': 'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE', 'value': 'DISTANCE'}, inplace=True)

df_main = pd.merge(merged, melt_df, left_on=['ANTENNA_ID', 'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE'], right_on=['ANTENNA_ID', 'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE'])

df_final = df_main.groupby(['USER', 'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE']).agg({'ANTENNA_ID': list, 'DISTANCE': sum}).reset_index()
df_final.rename(columns={'ANTENNA_ID':'CALL_LOC', 'DISTANCE': 'TRAVELLED_DISTANCE'}, inplace=True)

print(df_final)
```